# Where is Will's second outfit?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

Where can I find Will's second outfit?

I have all the gnomes, collectibles, heart pieces, and eggos. I don't have all the VHS tapes yet and still need Will's second outfit.

Answer (score 1):

In the library, after you defeat the guards with the flashlights and the lights are turned on. I’m sorry but I don’t remember exactly where it was inside, and it’s quite a big maze.

There are no VHSs anymore, I think that they replaced it for the outfits in this reboot of the game.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, welcome to Arqade! If you have another question, please ask it using the button on the main page.

Answer (score 1):

In the library on the top left hand side:

[image: Floorplan with library circled]